# StackNavigator: Set body style

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, native-base, stack-navigator

I am currently working at a project with a StackNavigator of React-Navigation: https://snack.expo.io/@pob/stacknavigator-problem. I use the Navigator in front of a background image and I want, that the body of each of its pages is transparent, so that you can see the background image through the StackNavigator.

I already found out how to set the style of the StackNavigator's header, but I have no idea how to set the style of its body. I would like to set the color of this body to `'transparent'`. Can anyone help?

[image: Screenshot of the example App]

Screenshot of the result I get with Hazim Ali's snack in iOS:
[image: Screenshot of the example App]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the body style should be added something like this if you want all screen in StackNavigator to have transparent background, and header not visible

```
const MyStackNavigator = new StackNavigator({
  ScreenOne: { screen: ScreenOne },  
},{
  cardStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
  },
  navigationOptions: {
    header: null
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it out, but the option "backgroundColor" doesn't support the value "transparent". Do you have any other idea?

Comment: that's weird, as backgroundColor always support "transparent", I already try with your code and it's working :-) check this one https://snack.expo.io/ryRw231J7 @Paul

Comment: When I open your snack, I can't see the background image through the StackNavigator, I can only see a black StackNavigator. So the problem is, that the StackNavigator's card is transparent, but behind it there is another black layer of the StackNavigator. Any idea to solve this? Or does your snack work at your device?

Comment: @Paul What do you means by black ? as I open, I can see the background image and the stackNavigator background become transparent.. so, I see text directly on top of the background image.. or are you looking for something else ?

Comment: I posted a picture of what I get with your snack... (see the question)

Comment: I tried your snack another time, this time in Android, and it worked. But in iOS I get what you see in the second picture of my question. Any idea how to solve the problem in iOS?

Comment: Ok, I will open a new topic for this specific question! Thank you!

Comment: That's the new topic, that I've opened: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462905/react-native-transparent-stack-navigator-in-ios-doesnt-work